# Buddypress Conditional Profile Fields

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Is there any way I can create custom/conditional registration/profile fields in buddypress.
I tried Googling a lot about this, but I am not getting proper solution.
The condition what I am thinking of is :

> I want to create 2/3 dropdowns, suppose if 1st one contains vehicles type(car, bike,),
>   then the second dropdown's option should change according to what user is choosing in dropdown 1.

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks a ton in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no working plugin or hack for that. I saw such thing on some sites - but this is done via JavaScript and heavily modifying of a registration page source code.

Comment: yes, i came to same conclusion. But what I am trying is if someone can guide me a bit about if it is possible through certain modification and adding few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It will be little tricky unless you touch register/resgistration.php source.
you can do like this if you little familiar with jquery.
Theres a hidden field ( id "signup_profile_field_ids" ) in buddypress registration form which tells server what fields in registration form, it will look like

```
<input type="hidden" name="signup_profile_field_ids" id="signup_profile_field_ids" value="5,11,1,10,32">
```

value of that field contains field ids of the registration form.

Now, you need to select a parent field to show conditional fields. you need to know parent and conditional field ids

now use this jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   var childs = new Array("Child id 1","Child id 1"); // your child fields ids
   var options = new Array("Car","Bike"); // your parent field options, notice option and child number is same, which means, one child for one option
   var parent = "Parent Field id"; // place you parent field id
   var currentFields = new Array();
   currentFields = $("#signup_profile_field_ids").val().split(','); // take all current fields ids in an array


   $.each(childs, function(index,value){
     $('#field_'+value).parent().hide(); // hide all child fields first
     currentFields.splice(currentFields.indexOf(value),1);
   });
   $("#signup_profile_field_ids").val( currentFields.join() );
   $('#field_'+parent).after('<div id="conditional-fields-conteiner></div>"');
   $('#field_'+parent).change(function(){
      var option = $(this).val();
      var appendField = childs[options.indexOf(option)];
      var html = $("#field_"+appendField).parent().html();
      $('#conditional-fields-conteiner').html(html);
      $.each(childs, function(index,value){
        currentFields.splice(currentFields.indexOf(value),1);
      });
      currentField[] = appendField;
       $("#signup_profile_field_ids").val( currentFields.join() );
    });
  });
</script>
```

This may seems complex, but this is the easiest approach. if you are planning it in membership site, dont use it. user can manupulate conditional fields simply by editing html.

Theres also a plugin for this, going to release soon. I am developing it

http://rimonhabib.com/coming-up-next-buddypress-nested-conditional-fields/